# Search results populating text boxes in winform. Wondering how to tab through results if more than one record is returned?

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, executenonquery

So I was successful after many attempts to search through the results of my query. Here is the code that worked for me.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=CD-FS02;Initial Catalog=engineering;Integrated Security=True");

    SqlDataAdapter da;

    DataTable ss = new DataTable();

    int pos = 0;
private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string str = "select * from engineering where (JobNumber like '%' + @search + '%' AND DateOrdered like '%' + @search1 + '%' AND Title like '%' + @search2 + '%' AND PhysicalAddressComplete like '%' + @search3 + '%' AND County like '%' + @search4 + '%' AND Client like '%' + @search5 + '%' AND Contact like '%' + @search6 + '%' AND ContactTitle like '%' + @search7 + '%' AND MailingAddressComplete like '%' + @search8 + '%' AND BusinessPhone like '%' + @search9 + '%' AND CellPhone like '%' + @search10 + '%' AND Email like '%' + @search11 + '%' AND OpenStatus like '%' + @search12 + '%' AND CloseStatus like '%' + @search13 + '%' AND Cabinet like '%' + @search14 + '%' AND Roll like '%' + @search15 + '%' AND Drawer like '%' + @search16 + '%' AND ConstructionDrawings like '%' + @search17 + '%' AND Fee like '%' + @search18 + '%' AND ConstructionCost like '%' + @search19 + '%' AND ProjectDescription like '%' + @search20 + '%')";
        SqlCommand xp = new SqlCommand(str, con);
        xp.Parameters.Add("@search", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtProjectNumber.Text;
        xp.Parameters.Add("@search1", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtDateOrdered.Text;
        xp.Parameters.Add("@search2", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtProjectName.Text;
        xp.Parameters.Add("@search3", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtProjectAddress.Text;
        xp.Parameters.Add("@search4", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtCounty.Text;
        xp.Parameters.Add("@search5", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtClient.Text;
        xp.Parameters.Add("@search6", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtClientContact.Text;
        xp.Parameters.Add("@search7", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtContactTitle.Text;
        xp.Parameters.Add("@search8", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtBillingAddress.Text;
        xp.Parameters.Add("@search9", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtBusinessPhone.Text;
        xp.Parameters.Add("@search10", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtCellPhone.Text;
        xp.Parameters.Add("@search11", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtEmail.Text;
        xp.Parameters.Add("@search12", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtOpenStatus.Text;
        xp.Parameters.Add("@search13", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtCloseStatus.Text;
        xp.Parameters.Add("@search14", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtCabinet.Text;
        xp.Parameters.Add("@search15", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtRoll.Text;
        xp.Parameters.Add("@search16", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtDrawer.Text;
        xp.Parameters.Add("@search17", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtDrawings.Text;
        xp.Parameters.Add("@search18", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtFee.Text;
        xp.Parameters.Add("@search19", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtCost.Text;
        xp.Parameters.Add("@search20", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtProjectDescription.Text;
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            xp.ExecuteNonQuery();
             da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            da.SelectCommand = xp;
            da.Fill(ss);
            Showdata(pos);

        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No Record Found");

        }


        con.Close();









    }

    public void Showdata(int index)
    {
        txtProjectNumber.Text = ss.Rows[index][0].ToString();
        txtDateOrdered.Text = ss.Rows[index][1].ToString();
        txtProjectName.Text = ss.Rows[index][2].ToString();
        txtProjectAddress.Text = ss.Rows[index][7].ToString();
        txtClient.Text = ss.Rows[index][3].ToString();
        txtClientContact.Text = ss.Rows[index][4].ToString();
        txtBillingAddress.Text = ss.Rows[index][5].ToString();
        txtContactTitle.Text = ss.Rows[index][6].ToString();
        txtBusinessPhone.Text = ss.Rows[index][8].ToString();
        txtProjectDescription.Text = ss.Rows[index][9].ToString();
        txtCloseStatus.Text = ss.Rows[index][10].ToString();
        txtOpenStatus.Text = ss.Rows[index][11].ToString();
        txtDrawer.Text = ss.Rows[index][12].ToString();
        txtCabinet.Text = ss.Rows[index][13].ToString();
        txtRoll.Text = ss.Rows[index][14].ToString();
        txtCounty.Text = ss.Rows[index][15].ToString();
        txtCellPhone.Text = ss.Rows[index][16].ToString();
        txtEmail.Text = ss.Rows[index][17].ToString();
        txtDrawings.Text = ss.Rows[index][18].ToString();
        txtFee.Text = ss.Rows[index][19].ToString();
        txtCost.Text = ss.Rows[index][20].ToString();


    }

    private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Controls.Clear();
        this.InitializeComponent();
        txtProjectNumber.Text = "";
        txtDateOrdered.Text = "";
        txtProjectName.Text = "";
        txtProjectAddress.Text = "";
        txtCounty.Text = "";
        txtClient.Text = "";
        txtClientContact.Text = "";
        txtContactTitle.Text = "";
        txtBillingAddress.Text = "";
        txtBusinessPhone.Text = "";
        txtCellPhone.Text = "";
        txtEmail.Text = "";
        txtOpenStatus.Text = "";
        txtCloseStatus.Text = "";
        txtCabinet.Text = "";
        txtRoll.Text = "";
        txtDrawer.Text = "";
        txtDrawings.Text = "";
        txtCost.Text = "";
        txtFee.Text = "";
        txtProjectDescription.Text = "";
    }

    private void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pos++;
        if(pos < ss.Rows.Count)
        {
            Showdata(pos);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Last Record Reached");
            pos = ss.Rows.Count - 1;
        }

    }

    private void btnPrevious_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pos--;
        if(pos >= 0)
        {
            Showdata(pos);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("First Record Reached");
        }
    }

    private void btnDrawings_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"F:\");
    }
}
```

}

The problem I am having now is that once I execute a search by clicking the search button, that is the only search that can be executed while the application is open, if I clear the textboxes and search again , it just returns the results of previous search. Any help with this would be appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried already?

Comment: I'm honestly stuck and not sure which direction to go. I haven't tried anything yet but I've looked everywhere for solutions.

Comment: Since the search result is obviously returning more than one result, AND there are 20 items in each result… have you considered using a `DataGridView` instead of a bunch of text boxes?